# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/gson/Gson;

Tags: java, android, android-studio-2.3

When I'm trying to run my application i get this error

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/gson/Gson;
```

this `com.google.gson.Gson` library file that I did added to my project through gradle and also added the libs/gson-2.8.1.jar file through Project Structure and can't understand when I have this problems.

Comment: can we see your `build.gradle` and `settings.gradle`?

Answer (score 2):

Here are a couple of reasons that this could be happening:

a) The library jar file is not being included

b) The wrong version of the jar file is being included

c) (if you are using maven) Another jar file is pulling in a newer/different version of the jar file

d) Your class path does not include the jar file.