# Unable to integrate library dependency to other app

Tags: android, android-library

I am facing  issue, I have multiple dependency in my library but when I create jitpack depenendency and try to integrate with other app, then logs of the app shows  `Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/gson/GsonBuilder;`but the dependency is present in the library module `api 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'` plz do provide suggestions. Thanks

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44340448/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-failed-resolution-of-lcom-google-gson-gson

Comment: I tried this 1 but no luck. Since my all dependency is in the android module. And I am trying to integrate it to standalone via using jitpack

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52670062/build-jitpack-library-with-multi-flavor-in-android